# use javaClass in lotusScript

Tags: java, lotus-domino, lotus

**Hello !**

First, excuse my poor english... :C

I try to use my Java Class in Domino Lotuscript.

I do that : in my Global Form

```
Option Public  
Uselsx "*javacon" 
Use "libEssai"
```

and in my button on Clic :

```
 Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim mySession As JAVASESSION    
    Dim utilDate As JAVACLASS
    Dim objUtilDate As JAVAOBJECT
    Dim toto As String  

    Set mySession = New  JAVASESSION    
    Set utilDate = mySession.GetClass("test/UtilDate")  
    Set objUtilDate = utilDate.CreateObject 
    toto = objUtilDate.essaiMethode
    Messagebox (toto + "*******************************************************")   
End Sub
```

I try to put this class in library java (Code /library/libEssai) and in a java package (Code/Java/ package test/UtilDAte.java)
i try the two way with the same result

it's a "hello word" class java to test.

```
package test;


public class UtilDate {

        public String essaiMethode() {
        String texte = null;        

            texte = "Bonjour";      

        return texte;
    }
}
```

And the error i have is :

```
"Instance member ESSAIMETHODE does not exist"
```

I don't understand, could you help me ?
Thanks for your help !
;D

i found !!

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim mySession As JAVASESSION    
    Dim utilDate As JAVACLASS
    Dim objUtilDate As JAVAOBJECT
    Dim toto As String
    Dim toto2 As String
    Dim myMCollection As JavaMethodCollection
    Dim myMethod As JavaMethod
    Dim methodJava As JavaMethod
    toto2 = "test"

    Set mySession = New  JAVASESSION    
    Set utilDate = mySession.GetClass("test/UtilEssai") 
    Set objUtilDate = utilDate.CreateObject


    Messagebox (toto2)

    Set myMCollection = utilDate.getClassMethods()

    Set myMethod = myMCollection.getFirst()
    Do
        If myMCollection.count <> 0 Then    
            toto2 =  myMethod.MethodName & " " & myMethod.signature
            Messagebox (toto2)

            If myMethod.MethodName = "essaiMethode" Then
                Set methodJava = utilDate.GetMethod("essaiMethode","()Ljava/lang/String;")
                toto = methodJava.Invoke(objUtilDate)           
                Messagebox (toto)
            End If

        End If
        Set myMethod = myMCollection.getNext()      
    Loop While myMCollection.current <> 1



End Sub
```

Comment: you can add the update as an answer and then accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found , thanks a lot !

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim mySession As JAVASESSION    
    Dim utilDate As JAVACLASS
    Dim objUtilDate As JAVAOBJECT
    Dim toto As String
    Dim toto2 As String
    Dim myMCollection As JavaMethodCollection
    Dim myMethod As JavaMethod
    Dim methodJava As JavaMethod
    toto2 = "test"

    Set mySession = New  JAVASESSION    
    Set utilDate = mySession.GetClass("test/UtilEssai") 
    Set objUtilDate = utilDate.CreateObject


    Messagebox (toto2)

    Set myMCollection = utilDate.getClassMethods()

    Set myMethod = myMCollection.getFirst()
    Do
        If myMCollection.count <> 0 Then    
            toto2 =  myMethod.MethodName & " " & myMethod.signature
            Messagebox (toto2)

            If myMethod.MethodName = "essaiMethode" Then
                Set methodJava = utilDate.GetMethod("essaiMethode","()Ljava/lang/String;")
                toto = methodJava.Invoke(objUtilDate)           
                Messagebox (toto)
            End If

        End If
        Set myMethod = myMCollection.getNext()      
    Loop While myMCollection.current <> 1



End Sub
```